# An $L^p$-bounded martingale that is not $L^{p+\epsilon}$-bounded

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, martingales

Is there an example of an $L^p$-bounded martingale (discrete-time/continuous-time) that is not $L^{p+\epsilon}$-bounded for any $\epsilon>0$?

For discrete time, my idea is to use $M_n = \prod_{j=1}^n \xi_j$ where $\xi_j$ are iid non-negative random variables with $\mathbb{E}\xi_j = 1,\mathbb{E}\xi_j^p = 1, \mathbb{E} \xi_j^{p+\epsilon}>1$.

What about continuous-time?

Comment: Just take some random variable $X \in L^p$, $X \notin L^{p+\epsilon}$, and define $M_t := X$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I don't get it... the OP didn't specify a filtration so I'm free to choose one... For $\mathcal{F}_t := \sigma(X)$ the process is clearly a martignale....or am I missing something?

Comment: No it is me. I removed my comment.

Comment: Would there be an interesting example if I has specified a non-trivial filtration, say a Brownian one?